# Alternative to word-wrap: break-word; in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, word-wrap

I did not find a question like this on the SE network.
I'm wondering if there's a alternative mathod for `word-wrap: break-word;` in Google Chrome.

It is working in all other browsers (as far as I can see: Firefox, Opera, IE9+)
I think this is a problem with Webkit because Chrome, Safari and Maxthon aren't working right.

I've tried several things like: Word-break, CSS4 hyphens etc. But nore of them work.
Hopefully there's a fix for this?

The problem occures at this page:

http://outletdokkum.nl/deelnemende-winkels/

Look at the urls, they're too long.

The code I'm using for this is:

HTML:

```
<div class="deelnemende-winkels">

      Generated content from wordpress (with urls)

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.deelnemende-winkel{
    width: àuto;
    min-width: 296px;
    max-width: 296px;
    min-height:450px;
    max-height: 450px;
    height: auto;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    margin:1px;
    padding:20px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: could you post an example and explain what is not working?

Comment: Added a link to the page where the problem exists.

Comment: You should describe the *problem*, in the question itself, with sufficient data to reconstruct it for testing, preferably with a jsfiddle too, and say exactly what the problem is (not just “URLs are too long”). Besides, arbitrary breaking (which is what you get with `word-wrap: break-word`) is not an appropriate way to deal with URLs (there are various rules on breaking them, but free breaking is just wrong).